# Extjs 4 MVC - Relative path problems with App.JS finding my controller - under WEB-INF with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4

Maybe the solution of my problem is contained in the question, but basically
I'm new to ExtJs 4 MVC and am having some difficulty where to place my JSPs.

I'm using Spring MVC using the Request Mapping annotation.

I'm having relative path problems with ExtJs App.JS finding my controller.

I usually put my JSPs under WEB-INF/views and my ExtJs 4 App is in WebContent/app.

I am trying to set up the example as shown on:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture

and in the example the index.html is contained in the app package.

So I have a view called WEB-INF/views/sample-view.jsp and this includes the app.js script, which works fine. 
My app has a controller like the example, and this is the problem, because it seems to try to find that internally in ExtJs using the appFolder, and controllers.

This resource can't be found, because my view is in another package all together.  Does this make sense ?

Should I just move my view out of WEB-INF ? And if so will Spring MVC complain?

Thanks,

Lisa

Answer (score 3):

For the first attempt at getting this running it is easiest to use all static files just to keep things simple.  Once the app is running from static html and js files, migration can then be made to use the spring mvc and jsp pages.

To start be sure there is a folder named resources under the webapp folder, assuming webapp is the parent of your existing WEB-INF folder.

The basic starting folder structure for using a static html page will be:

```
    webapp
    - resources
    -- app
    -- css
    --- ext-all.css
    -- sass
    -- themes
    - WEB-INF
    -- spring
    -- classes
    -- views
    index.html
    app.js
    ext-all-debug.js
```

In WEB-INF there is likely a spring folder with an mvc-config.xml file or similar. In that config file the resources folder needs to be designated for serving static content by using the resources tag.  Likely, the first mvc:annotation-driven tag is alrleady in the config file as in this snipped below. Add the resources tag noted below into the config file.

```
        <!-- Configures support for @Controllers -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
        <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

With this in place the resources folder can serve the index.html file much like setup of the Sencha example.

All of this is setting you up to be able to build the first example from a url like:
http://localhost:8080/resources/index.html

When downloaded and extracted, the Ext JS zip, contains a resources folder.  Copy the subfolders of that folder into the webapp/resources folder.  Also copy ext-all.debug.js to the webapp/resources folder.

Then create index.html in webapp/resources with this content similar to the Sencha tutorial:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Static Account Manager</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/ext-all.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./ext-all-debug.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Create app.js in the webapp/resources folder as the following snippet and enough is in place to be up and running with the single panel configured in app.js.  From this point the tutorial is easy enough to port over to this setup.

```
    Ext.application({
            name: 'AM',
            appFolder: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                                            layout: 'fit',
                                             items: [
                    {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Users',
                    html : 'List of users will go here'
                     }
                      ]
               });
       }
   });
```

After that static html file is running correctly, a jsp can be used from the view folder and will have content like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>JSP Account Manager</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resoures/css/ext-all.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./resoures/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./resoures/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks John, I think I was trying to swim before I could walk.

Comment: No problem Lisa!  I hope this works out well for you.  Ext JS works very nicely with spring mvc for large and small apps.

Answer (score 0):

a bit off topic, but if you are going to use Spring MVC might as well use Grails - you will save yourself a lot of typing and figuring out bunches of config files.