# RX on windows azure

Tags: azure, system.reactive

I'm have azure queues over my applications and agents that cosumes the events on the queues. However each agent keep checking the queue to see if there is any events on it. Is there any way to use Rx on windows Azure queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to abstract the polling into observables, you could just create a `Observable.Interval(...)` which polls the queue, and then use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext.Loader.setPath to assign the path.

[path of view is incorrect in extjs 4 mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152508/path-of-view-is-incorrect-in-extjs-4-mvc-application)

For your reference:
[Extjs 4 MVC - Relative path problems with App.JS finding my controller - under WEB-INF with Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019602/extjs-4-mvc-relative-path-problems-with-app-js-finding-my-controller-under-w)

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment, since it merely references other posts on [so].