# path of view is incorrect in extjs 4 mvc application

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to deploy my mvc app into my large web application. I have defined the app folder and can see in fire bug that it is calling the correct files with the exception of the initial view. So

"App.view.Jobs" is calling

https://www.estore.localhost/Jobs/Edit/ext/jobs/App/view/Jobs.js?_dc=1328471746967

when i would like it to call

https://www.estore.localhost/ext/jobs/App/view/Jobs.js?_dc=1328471746967

```
  Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
    Ext.application({

        name: 'MyApp',
        appFolder: '/ext/jobs/app',

        models: ['Part', 'Material', 'Job', 'Process'],
        stores: ['SalesContact', 'Parts', 'Materials', 'Jobs', 'AccountHandlers', 'JobTypes', 'Processs', 'Artwork', 'Varnish', 'VarnishType', 'PrintType', 'ProofRequired', 'InvoiceDetails', 'PurchaseOrders'],
        controllers: ['Part', 'Material', 'Job', 'Process', 'Invoice'],

        launch: function () {

            Ext.QuickTips.init();
            var cmp1 = Ext.create('App.view.Jobs', {
                renderTo: "form-job"
            });
            cmp1.show();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to answer my own question.   You can use setPath to assign the path.

like so...

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
Ext.Loader.setPath('App', '/ext/jobs/app');
Ext.application({

    name: 'Pandora',
    appFolder: '/ext/jobs/app',

    models: ['Part', 'Material', 'Job', 'Process'],
    stores: ['SalesContact', 'Parts', 'Materials', 'Jobs', 'AccountHandlers', 'JobTypes', 'Processs', 'Artwork', 'Varnish', 'VarnishType', 'PrintType', 'ProofRequired', 'InvoiceDetails', 'PurchaseOrders'],
    controllers: ['Part', 'Material', 'Job', 'Process', 'Invoice'],

    launch: function () {

        Ext.QuickTips.init();
        var cmp1 = Ext.create('App.view.Jobs', {
            renderTo: "form-job"
        });
        cmp1.show();
    }

});
```

Comment: add one more thing in launch function:    Pandora.app: this;

Answer (score 0):

This is easier if you use relative paths in  appFolder as:

appFolder:'../../app'