# Import extJs to JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4

I am using Spring tool suite and I created MVC application. Now I'd like to move to ExtJs with this concept.

But I am not able to include extJs files into JSP.

My servlet looks like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spingextjs" />
```

my JSP looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="extjs/ext-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Folder tree looks like this:

[image: Tree of folders]

However page won't load and firelogger says that /extjs/ext-debug.js and app/app.js is not located on server (404 on these files). I use tomcat and trying it on localhost.

So my question is, what should I do to import ExtJs in JSP, or should I change home.jsp to home.html (tried this, didn't helped)?

I already made the ExtJs app using static web page and loading in html, however I am not able to force server to load ExtJs using MVC concept.

Comment: why would you think changing the file extension of the source file would affect the fact that you have the wrong path to the other files ( or the files are not there ). Does that make any logical sense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extjs 4 MVC - Relative path problems with App.JS finding my controller - under WEB-INF with Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019602/extjs-4-mvc-relative-path-problems-with-app-js-finding-my-controller-under-w)

Comment: I wrote that at 9 am, it was desperate try to rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your js/css/images need to be located in the `resources` folder.

There are a bunch of examples of using ExtJS with Spring MVC out there:

https://github.com/loiane/extjs-crud-grid

It relies on an older version of Ext but it's a nice boilerplate.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may need to **MOVE** extjs/ext-debug.js and app/app.js into the **resources** directory because the other locations will be handled by a dispatcher servlet.

**OR**, if you do not want to move these files, then add two line in your servlet configuration.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/extjs/**" location="/extjs/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/app/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spingextjs" />
```

**If it does not solve the problem** after you have moved or added two lines in the configuration file, then try the jstl c:url tag like below.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="<c:url value='/resources/css/ext-all.css' />" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="<c:url value='/extjs/ext-debug.js' />" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<c:url value='/resources/css/ext-all.css' />app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried all of these before asking, didn't worked as I needed. However moving into resources and changing path in app.js helped, thank you.